# mysql hangs while alter a big table

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has around 40 columns and it has more than 1 million rows of data.if i add a new column to that database with default value 'Null', the phpmyadmin hangs.

Comment: What is your question, what do you want to change? Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i need to avoid hang problem

Comment: with no default value you have the same problem? you have a timeout error at one point? what do you see in "show processlist" while creating the row?
Did you try to check table for errors?

Comment: Working as intended.

Comment: Copy the data into a new table.  Truncate the existing table, change the structure, and re-insert.

Comment: mysql and sql are not the same thing.  Please show your code.